# Unable to append, to an html element, values of an array of objects passed as parameter to jQuery each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I have an array of objects, that I loop through using $.each and try and append the array object value to an `<li>`.

Please find the jQuery below

```
$(".sidebar").empty().append("<div>"+
  "<h5>Student Info</h5>" +
  "<ul>" +
     $.each(studentInfo, function (index, value) { 
        console.log(value.studentName + " :studentName ");//prints the student name in the browser console
        "<li>Student No " + index + "</li>" 
        "<li>Name - " + value.studentName + "</li>" 
        "<li>Contact - " + value.contact + "</li>"
        "<li>DOB - " + value.dob + "</li>"
        "<li>PAN - " + value.PANNo + "</li>"
        "<li>Address - " + value.postalAddress + "</li>"
      }) +
   "</ul>" +
 "</div>")
```

The above function only prints `[object Object],[object Object]` in the `<li>`. I have tried stringifying the array, parsing the array, different ways of appending json objects but its still the same.

The array of objects that I am trying to loop through

```
var studentInfo = [
  {
   "studentName":"abc",
   "contact":"123456789",
   "dob":"22-05-1994",
   "PANNo":"ABCDEF1234",
   "postalAddress":"chandigarh, sector - 18"
  },
  {
   "studentName":"xyz",
   "contact":"123456987",
   "dob":"22-05-1994",
   "PANNo":"ABCDEF4321",
   "postalAddress":"chandigarh, sector - 78"
  }
]
```

I have been at it for hours but unable to figure out what I am doing wrong, I am still new at jQuery and its ways. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're not actually appending the loop. `"<li>Student No " + index + "</li>"` is just a statement that does nothing. This is not a map, so you don't return that value or append it to the string outside. When I change the code to `studentInfo.map()` and then return that html string you're building in the loop, everything works as expected.

Comment: @Shilly I get it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery `$.each()` is not meant to return a string. you use it to treat each object separately. You can't just parse it as string expression.

You will need to split your code into multiple parts.

Part 1: clear `.sidebar` and prep it for the menu items.

Part 2: build a string `items` that contain all the object values parsed into HTML list-items.

Part 3: append the string to the '.sidebar'

```js
var studentInfo = [
  {
   "studentName":"abc",
   "contact":"123456789",
   "dob":"22-05-1994",
   "PANNo":"ABCDEF1234",
   "postalAddress":"chandigarh, sector - 18"
  },
  {
   "studentName":"xyz",
   "contact":"123456987",
   "dob":"22-05-1994",
   "PANNo":"ABCDEF4321",
   "postalAddress":"chandigarh, sector - 78"
  }
];

var items = "";
$.each(studentInfo, function (index, value) { 
        console.log(value.studentName + " :studentName ");
        items += "<li>Student No " + index + "</li>" 
                  + "<li>Name - " + value.studentName + "</li>" 
                  +  "<li>Contact - " + value.contact + "</li>"
                  + "<li>DOB - " + value.dob + "</li>"
                  + "<li>PAN - " + value.PANNo + "</li>"
                  + "<li>Address - " + value.postalAddress + "</li>" 
                  + "<hr>" ;
      })
 +

$(".sidebar").empty().append("<div>"+
  "<h5>Student Info</h5>" +
  "<ul>" + items  + "</ul></div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar"></div>
```

Comment: This works ! thanks. I now understand the mistake I was making.